# The While statement stop at four

Tags: python

I need to write a function called `stop_at_four` that iterates through a list of numbers using a `while` loop, append each number to a new list until the number 4 appears. The function should return the new list.

This is my code:

```
def stop_at_four(x):
    new_list=[]
    accum=0
    while x[accum]!=4:
        new_list.append(x[accum])
        accum+=1
    return new_list
```

But there are still error in this which I think I should stop running it when the list come to the end but how I should correct it?

I get the following error:

> Error: IndexError: list index out of range

I had tried this as well:

```
def stop_at_four(x):
    new_list=[]
    accum=0
    while accum<len(x):
        if x[accum]!=4:
            new_list.append(x[accum])
            accum+=1
    return new_list
```

Comment: Are you sure there is a number 4 on the list that the function is receiving? (I mean `x`)
For your second example. Did you remember that lists start its index in 0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is fine, there are  only 2 issues with it:

1. You don't handle the case where the list is empty
2. You don't consider a case where 4 is not present in the list

A fix to your code is:

```
def stop_at_four(x):
    # empty list case
    if not x:
        return x
    new_list=[]
    accum=0
    # making sure accum wont exceed the list len
    while accum < len(x) and x[accum]!=4:
        new_list.append(x[accum])
        accum+=1
    return new_list
```

So the first condition is just to make sure that the list contain anything. The second (in the case you wish to use `while` loop) is to first check if `accum` is greater the the list length, if so the condition will be `False` and the loop will break.

Note that in this specific case I would use a `for` loop and iterate over the element of the list in the following way: `for elem in x:` then you won't have any issues with indexing.

Comment: `accum < len(x) and x[accum]!=4 `, is it matter which come first and which come next for `and` statenment

Comment: @GEH_L yes. If this `x[accum]!=4` comes first and `accum` is larger then `len(x)` you will get the error you recived, but for the opposite if the first condition is `False` python will stop and return `False` for the condition

Answer (score 0):

The code loops forever when the list `x` does have `4`.

because `accum` as iterator does not updated if `x[accum]` find `4` in loop.

let's follow the code step by step.

As `x = [1,4]`, when it is `acuum=0` and `x[0] != 4` is True. then, `accum` is `1` now by `accum+=1` in first loop.

In the second loop, `x[1] != 4` is False BUT `accum` is NOT updated forever because of it can be changed only when the condition is True.

```py
def stop_at_four(x):
    new_list=[]
    accum=0
    while accum<len(x):
         if x[accum] != 4:
              new_list.append(x[accum])
              accum+=1
         else:        # Add here
               break  # to break
    return new_list


print(stop_at_four([1,2,3,4,5,6]))
```

Answer (score 0):

**Is this what you want? if the list doesn't contain 4 it stop immediately and no errors will take place. And if we pass in a empty list it stop immediately**

```py
def stop_at_four(lst):
    if len(lst) != 0:
        if 4 in lst:
            new_list = []

            for ele in lst:
              if lst[ele] != 4:
                  new_list.append(lst[ele])
              else:
                  break
            return new_list
        else:
            print("List doesn't contain 4!")
    else:
        print("Empty Lists Not Acccepted!")

print(stop_at_four([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]))
```

Hope this solves your problem

Answer (score 0):

Most probably the error would occur when you pass an empty list to your function, try checking the length, and yes you have to check if 4 is present in the list or not, return the list as it is in those cases.

```
def stop_at_four(x):
    if len(x)<1 or 4 not in x:
        return(x)
    else:
        new_list=[]
        accum=0
        while x[accum]!=4:
            new_list.append(x[accum])
            accum+=1
        return new_list
```

Answer (score 0):

In your second approach, you'll have to squash both conditions together, to avoid infinite looping (it doesn't break out of the loop if the element is 4)

`while accum < len(x) and x[accum] != 4:`